# MVC3 application I want javascript methods to fire on passed in route values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 application in Visual Studio 2010.

I have a view with several dropdowns that do javascript calls to populate dropdowns based on the selected value, some of which are disabled initially.

That all works great with the initial state of nothing. If I however pass routevalues to the dropdowns from a redirect to this action, I do get the value set correctly but it's not enabled like it should be on the dropdown for example and when I post the form, the ones that are greyed out are not passed back on the form.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Im not sure I follow what you are doing. Are you saying you are using jquery to post to a controller action to get data to populate your dropdowns with, and the problem is that they are not re-enabling? Can you post the view code, and the jquery

Comment: I have a view with 3 dropdowns.  The 1st drop down is enabled and you select an item.  Based on that item the next dropdown is populated via jquery call.  Select the item in that drop down and it populates the 3rd dropdown with jquery call and enables it.   I want the ability to route to this view directly from another view passing it prepopulated values.  I have it working in the fact the values are correct when the view is displayed.. however the dropdowns are not enabled and when I post the form it doesn't pass the fields in the form for the 2 drop downs that are disabled. cannot post code.

Comment: so would an on document ready jquery statement work to check if any of your dropdowns have options, if they do, enable them, if they dont hide them? I can post some quick code for that.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the view when it's rendered... it won't even "reset" the page to it's default state when I call resetForm or set the val() to '' or 0.  If i do this same call on the one with no passed in values.. it's fine.  Resets everything ok.    What I really need i think is a way to fire those same methods programatically when values are passed to the action and to not set the dropdown's value.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled form fields **do not** get `POST`ed. Have the value of each dropdown in a separate hidden field so that on from POST it is received on the server.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.SomeID_1)
```

or

```
<%:Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.SomeID_1)%>
```

Another solution is to make them readonly but that way you dont get to edit them in the edit view